# Python series bar chart labels not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot, bar-chart

I have an issue setting the bar chart x labels, here is my code:

[image]

In the x label should be shown "something" as the documentation specify instead is "Education_Level"

Answer (score 0):

To set different xlabel other than the column name use:

```
plt.xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=18)
```